# How to set references/bibliography page in Word /Endnote?

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography, endnote

I am inserting my references into my document however whenever I insert references Endnote always places them on the last page of my document.

How can I tell Endnote that i want it to place all my references on page 32 and not my last page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just move the bibliography (select + cut/paste or drag) to where you want it in your document. Existing and future references will be listed together at this point, as you've now moved the target document-location for the bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

hello fellas i had that problem tooo and it almost killing me :(( finally after working days on it  found the solution and it was very easy all u need to do is this:

1. right click on your bibliography .
2. choose toggle field codes.
3. after  step2 you will see your long list will turn in to this: {ADDIN EN.REFLIST}.
4. now drag it to any place you want.
   (if you choose all list manually and drag it , your document will crash and functions wont work, so here its is :))))))))
   office 2016+ endnote x9(works on x20 too)

Answer (score 0):

You can compile endnotes anywhere in a document. Just position the insertion point where you want the endnotes compiled and insert an Endnote Placement code.

Choose Insert, Footnote/Endnote.
Select Endnote, Endnote Placement.
Make your selection. 
Choose OK all the way back out.

This should work the way you want. If not, write back and let us know.

Source - @Laura Acklen http://www.wpuniverse.com/vb/showthread.php?7268-Endnotes-not-on-last-page

Comment: I think he's referring to the EndNote product for referencing not endnotes...

Comment: Oh just spotted the microsoft-word tag, hopefully @beardbread... interesting name, will clarify =)